# Unity having "Damaged Packages" upon reinstall over Gnome 3

Tags: unity, gnome, dependencies

When I got Gnome installed over Unity, on login I couldn't chose to return to the standard Unity desktop. Every time I attempt the simple

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I get the error

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
  Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried everything, but Unity refuses to reinstall, and I don't wan't to reinstall Ubuntu completely. I use Ubuntu 14.04. Please Help!!!

Comment: `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f `.Also mention the version of Ubuntu you are using in question.

Comment: allready installed, can uninstall libupower-glib2 as it is optional.

Comment: How did you installed gnome, by adding gnome PPA or from Ubuntu Rrepo ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install

Comment: What error it is giving if you are  trying  `sudo apt-get install unity-settings-daemon` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something went wrong and now the package dependencies are broken.
Go through the steps in [How do I resolve unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)
to get things back in order.

Basically that's

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -f install ubuntu-desktop
```

Make sure you keep the output from these commands. If it's still broken after that it'll give valuable info about what's going on.

Comment: same exact error

Comment: Interesting, try [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113213&p=12496996#post12496996) then, ie `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` to find out about held packages and using `aptitude` instead of apt-get to try and fix things.

Comment: Yeah, but I had to use an alternative install option. But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue disabling all gnome3-staging repositories (in software-central) and reinstalling all the package dependencies.

After trying to install each dependency (and it's sub-dependencies) with `apt-get install`, it showed me that I has some newer versions of some libraries.

To solve it, I removed and installed each one of these newer versions.